# Does a Russian need a separate New Zealand visa for a cruise that docks in New Zealand?

Tags: visas, new-zealand, cruising, russian-citizens

I am a Russian citizen. At the moment I have obtained an Australian tourist visa to cruise. Voyage starts from Sydney and ship will be docking at New Zealand ports as well.

Do I need a New Zealand visa?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you will not be there for more than 28 days and will leave with the vessel when it leaves, no need for a visa:

> **You must have a valid passport**
>
> You must have a passport that is valid for three months after  the
> date you intend to leave New Zealand.
>
> **Deemed to hold a visa**
>
> If you are a passenger or a crew member of a cruise ship in  New
> Zealand you are deemed to hold a visitor or work visa  for 28 days
> from arrival, or until the ship leaves (whichever  occurs first).
>
> If
> you leave the ship and stay on in New Zealand, you must  obtain a
> further visa. You must apply for the visa before the  expiry of your
> deemed visa by completing a passenger arrival  card and presenting it
> to a New Zealand Customs officer.
>
> If you remain in New Zealand and you
> do not have a current  visa you will be here unlawfully, and you may
> be deported.
>
> Only passengers and crew who arrive on the ship will be
> deemed to hold a visa. If you fly into New Zealand to  join the  ship
> you must apply for a visa in the normal way.

From [IMMIGRATION New Zealand](http://www.customs.govt.nz/news/resources/Documents/INZ1089.pdf).